# SMTP client only sends to my server?

Tags: c#, smtpclient

So I'm practising some C#, trying to make simple email client. I've got as far as using the SMTP server from the mail server I pay for to send plain text... however it only lets me send emails to my own server (which currently only has my address on it). I've tried emailing both my own, and my wife's, Gmail addresses but it brings back an error stating:

"System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: **Mailbox unavailable**.

The server response was:  **No such user** here at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)

at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

at TinyMail.TinyMail.buildMail() in C:\Users\hinton\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TinyMail\TinyMail\TinyMail.cs:**line 82**"

Code used for sending the MailMessage is below, server credentials have been blanked:

```
private void buildMail()
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("*********@*****.com", "*********");
            SmtpServer.Host = "mail.***********.***";
            SmtpServer.Port = 587; 

            MailMessage Mail = new MailMessage();

            Mail.To.Add(txtTarget.Text);
            Mail.From = new MailAddress(txtSender.Text);
            Mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
            Mail.Body = txtBody.Text;

            SmtpServer.Send(Mail);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.ToString());
            txtBody.Text = e.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand your question. Are there one or two mail servers involved? Which program generates the error messages you show, your client program or the mail server (or one of the two mail servers involved)? It also seems strange that the error messages you show don't list the email address that it says failed.

Comment: There should be just one server involved. I'm using the server details of an SMTP server that came with my webmail service. I can send an email to myself using my little app, but I can't send anything to other people.

Comment: OK, this is not something I know anything about, sorry. But first off, could you do me (and yourself, I think) a favor and make it a habit that you name variables with leading-lowercase names, and, at least to some extent, with names the match or resemble the class name, or indicate what they are used for. So your "SmtpServer" should be "smtpClient", and your "Mail" should be "mailMessage". Then you end up with a statement "smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);" This obviously won't fix your problem, but it makes your program easier to understand.

Comment: Only suggestion I have regarding your problem is that your authentication string may be wrong. Instead of the full email address try just specifying the mailbox part, the part before "@".

Comment: More on C# naming conventions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx This is especially for those who are creating their own framework extensions or layers, but a good idea to follow for all programs.

Comment: Have just discovered that my webmail provider had changed the password for the user account I had been using, since updating it all seems to be fine. Thanks again.